# How to use parameters for table names and field name in oledb command statement when updating a MS Access table?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access

Sorry if the question didn't make sense, couldn't figure out how to word the question. I'm trying to update a table of the users choice(`Dim tblName As String = SelectedTable`) with a column/field of the users choice(`Dim colName As String = txtColumnName.Text`) and the data they want to update(`Dim NewData As String = txtSelectedCellData.Text`) based on the ID(`Dim recID As String = txtID.Text`)

However when clicking the `btnUpdateTables` I receive an error stating: "Syntax eror in query. Incomplete query statement." Here is the statement:

`Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("UPDATE @tblName SET @colName = @NewData WHERE ID = @recID", con)`

I don't know what's wrong with the query statement as I have never used parameters for the table name and column name. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Here is the code for the button:

```
Private Sub btnUpdateTable_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdateTable.Click
        Dim tblName As String = SelectedTable
        Dim colName As String = txtColumnName.Text
        Dim recID As String = txtID.Text
        Dim NewData As String = txtSelectedCellData.Text

        Try
            Dim con As New OleDbConnection(connString)
            con.Open()
            Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("UPDATE @tblName SET @colName = @NewData WHERE ID = @recID", con)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            cm.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@tblName", OleDbType.VarChar, 255, tblName))
            cm.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@colName", OleDbType.VarChar, 255, colName))
            cm.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@NewData", OleDbType.VarChar, 255, NewData))
            cm.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@recID", OleDbType.VarChar, 255, recID))

            cm.Parameters("@tblName").Value = tblName
            cm.Parameters("@colName").Value = colName
            cm.Parameters("@NewData").Value = NewData
            cm.Parameters("@recID").Value = recID

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        End Try

    End Sub
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Your command `UPDATE @tblName SET @colName = @NewData WHERE ID = @recID` will not work this way. As the name says, a parameter is not a table/column name, but the value.

Comment: @muffi so how would I get the value based on the textbox? Thank you.

Comment: Think about how parameters work in VB. Can you pass in the name of a variable or the like using a parameter when you call a method in VB? Of course not. You pass in values.  That's exactly how parameters work in SQL.

Comment: You can't do it this way. Instead you will have to build up the query. Look into dynamic SQL. It's a bit messy though.

Comment: I would use a combo box drop down list to select the table name and then fill a second drop down with the field names based on the table selection. Letting the user type in a text box is asking for trouble.

Comment: Problem is @Mary I have made it so that when a user clicks a cell in the data grid view they can change the value of the desired cell and so an update query is run when they click the update button. I'm also unsure of how to put field names and table names into a combo box and it could be incredibly helpful! Thank you

Comment: Oh, I see. I am guessing that your datagrid is bound. Yes? If so the update can be handled by the data adapter and data set. You are making it too complicated. Check Microsoft docs for DataAdapter.Update(DataSet). There is a good VB example there.

Comment: Ohhh really? So if I only make the datagridview read only = false for the admin, they should be able to update the database itself by directly typing into the datagridview? How does that work? I looked at the article but I don't really understand it.

Answer (score 1):

Only values can be parameters. You're using parameters for your table name and your column name. That's just not possible.

You can use string concatenation instead, but this will introduce a risk of SQL injection:

```
Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("UPDATE ["& tblName & "] SET [" & colName & "] = @NewData WHERE ID = @recID", con)
```

To mitigate the risk of SQL injection, you can do several things, like use ADO or query the MSysObjects table to verify the existence of a table with that name and the existence of a column with that name in the table.

Comment: What is a SQL injection? If I'm making a program for a year 11 school project will this be a concern? Also I still receive an error sating No value given for one or more parameters. Do I need to remove some of the oledb add parameter statements with the new line of text you've given me? Thank you.

Comment: You need to remove both the tablename and colname parameters. For SQL injection, consult a resource, that's a pretty broad topic. If you fully trust all users to have total access to the database, you can not worry about it, else you should do something about it.

Comment: yeah that's okay, only the admin can use these functions

Comment: I removed the lines to create the parameters for colname and tblname and I still receive the same error. Thanks again.

Comment: Are you sure all columns exist (ID, the one you entered as column name) in the specified table?

Comment: Yep I'm pretty sure they are all correct. The ID in both the tables is called "ID".

Comment: @EthanPayne you can't have any parameter values be null. Check if any are. If null is what you want in the database use `DBNull.Value` as the value.